# How to initialize a static array?

Tags: java, arrays, static, playing-cards

I have seen different approaches to define a static array in Java.  Either:

```
String[] suit = new String[] {
  "spades", 
  "hearts", 
  "diamonds", 
  "clubs"  
};
```

...or only

```
String[] suit = {
  "spades", 
  "hearts", 
  "diamonds", 
  "clubs"  
};
```

or as a `List`

```
List suit = Arrays.asList(
  "spades", 
  "hearts", 
  "diamonds", 
  "clubs"  
);
```

Is there a difference (except for the List definition of course)?

What is the better way (performance wise)?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

If you are creating an array then there is no difference, however, the following is neater:

```
String[] suit = {
  "spades", 
  "hearts", 
  "diamonds", 
  "clubs"  
};
```

But, if you want to pass an array into a method you have to call it like this:

```
myMethod(new String[] {"spades", "hearts"});

myMethod({"spades", "hearts"}); //won't compile!
```

Answer (score 9):

Nope, no difference. It's just [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). `Arrays.asList(..)` creates an additional list.