# How to initialize a final object array

Tags: java, arrays, static, initialization, final

I'm trying to add an array of object in my class(MainActivity), for example

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private class A {
      A(String s) { ..}
    }
    private static final A[] aList1;
    private static final List<A> aList2;
    ...
```

both are ok with me.

But I don't know how to initialize aList1 or aList2. Had already tried following:

```
private static final A[] aList;
static {
    a = new A[2];
    a[0] = new A("emails");
}
```

And also tried:

```
private static final List<A> aList = new ArrayList<A>(){{
    add(new A("emails"));
}};
```

but eclipse are complaining: `No enclosing instance of type MainActivity is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type MainActivity (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of MainActivity).`

How to fix this?

Comment: What is `A`? Where is `MainActivity`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980199/how-to-initialize-a-static-array

Comment: It sounds like we're not getting the full story. What's the deal with the inner class?

Comment: @Deqing I've updated my answer. I think I understood now your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understood your problem now. You have a inner class `A` declared inside your class `MainActivity`, right? Well, in this case you wont be able to initialize your `static final` variables since you gonna need an instance of `MainActivity` to create a new instance of `A`. What I suggest you to do is to make your class `A` a static class

```
private static class A {
    // code here
}
```

so that you will be able to instantiate as

```
A a = new MainActivity.A("someString");
```

and the variables initialization as

```
private static final A[] aList;

static {
    a = new A[2];
    a[0] = new MainActivity.A("emails");
}
```

Comment: The problem solved by declaring my inner class A as `static`. Btw as the `aList` is defined inside `MainActivity` so it is ok to use `A a = new A("emails");`

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList is better than List. It has more methods. Sample:

```
private static final A[] aList2;
private static final ArrayList<A> aList = new ArrayList<A>(); //you can add in static aList=new ArrayList<a>();

....or...
static {
    aList = new ArrayList(a):
    aList.add(new A("emails"));
}
```

To convert the array to A[]:

```
A[] array = new A[aList.size()];
array = aList.toArray(array);
```

To fast gets value:

```
for (A item : aList) {
    ... do somme with item
}
```

To gets any item: aList.get(int index);

Answer (score 0):

`final` fields can only be initialized inline and in the constructor.

```
private static final A[] aList = new A[2];
```

After that you can use the static initializer

```
static {
 aList[0] = new A("emails");
}
```

or with a list

```
private static final List<A> aList = new ArrayList<>();

static {
 aList.add(new A("example"));
}
```

Comment: Looks like I should add constructor to `MainActivity` and place the initializer in it?